# WPF main app dynamically invoking a DLL...need messaging from the DLL prior to the return to the main app

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic, dll, messaging

I've done a lot of googling and searching here on stackoverflow but can't figure out how to get progress messages back from a dynamically called DLL prior to returning from the DLL.  Let say the DLL is 10% finished...I want to show that progress.  I'm used to just displaying what returns from a call but in this case I need the progress.  Here is my code (C#, WPF project) to invoke the DLL.  Just curious how to get messages back prior to the return...

```
string pathAndDLLFile = Path.GetFullPath(DLLName + ".DLL");
Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFile(pathAndDLLFile);
string typeField = DLLNamespace + "." + DLLClass;
Type myType = a.GetType(typeField);
MethodInfo testMethod = myType.GetMethod(DLLMethod);
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
object c = testMethod.Invoke(obj, new Object[] { nodeChild });
```

Here is my DLL...

```
using System.Xml;

namespace InitialTest2
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public int test(XmlNode xmlTest)
        {
            int testCount = 0;
            int progress = 0;
            foreach (XmlAttribute attributeChild in xmlTest.Attributes)
            {
                if (attributeChild.Name != "name" && attributeChild.Name != "testNumber" && attributeChild.Name != "Estimate" && !attributeChild.Name.Contains("DLL"))
                {
                    if ((attributeChild.Name.Contains("MinLimit")) || (attributeChild.Name.Contains("MaxLimit")) || (attributeChild.Name.Contains("Unit")))
                    {
                        // not the attribute value
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        testCount ++;
                    }
                }
                progress = progress + 1;
                // ToDo: report progress back to the main ap

            }
            return testCount;

        }
        public int test3(XmlNode xmlTest)
        {
            return 3;
        }
    }
    public class Class2
    {
        public int test2(XmlNode xmlTest)
        {
            return 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Um, yeah. We cannot help. We do not know anything about the dll, about the class and neither about the specific method you are calling. Usually, there are some particular methods to report progress (if it is at all supported). One would be a call-back-method that you pass along, then there could be an event for which to register and since there is async/await and Tasks, there is IProgress ... But really, you need to tell us more about that dll ...

Comment: Posting my DLL (above).  Very simple.  Loops through and processes tests.  At the end of each processed tests, I need to report back to the main app without end returning from the call.

Comment: @ScottS: Your `test` method returns a single `int` value and nothing else. Such a method cannot report or return anything else than an `int` value back to the caller. How and where are you expect to get the current value of the local variable `progress`? You don't return from the method until after the `foreach` loop has been completed anyway.

Comment: When you use return in the DLL then the call is over, correct?  I need a way to have messaging while the call is in underway but not finished yet.  Is there a way to return data more than once?  I need to report progress back during the call.

Comment: "Is there a way to return data more than once"? If you return an enumerable sequence or a stream of values as I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with dynamic invocation but the fact is that tour `test` method returns a single `int` value and nothing else.

Such a method cannot report or return anything else than an `int` value back to the caller. How and where are you expect to get the current value of the local variable `progress`? You don't return anything from the method until after the `foreach` loop has been completed.

If you want to return some kind of progress, or at least several values, from a synchronous method, you could change its return type to `IEnumerable<int>` and iterate over the return values, e.g.:

```
public IEnumerable<int> test(XmlNode xmlTest)
{
    int testCount = 0;
    int progress = 0;
    foreach (XmlAttribute attributeChild in xmlTest.Attributes)
    {
        if (attributeChild.Name != "name" && attributeChild.Name != "testNumber" && attributeChild.Name != "Estimate" && !attributeChild.Name.Contains("DLL"))
        {
            if ((attributeChild.Name.Contains("MinLimit")) || (attributeChild.Name.Contains("MaxLimit")) || (attributeChild.Name.Contains("Unit")))
            {
                // not the attribute value
            }
            else
            {
                testCount++;
            }
        }
        yield return progress + 1;
        // ToDo: report progress back to the main ap

    }
    yield return testCount;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
IEnumerable<int> c = testMethod.Invoke(obj, new Object[] { nodeChild }) as IEnumerable<int>;
if (c != null)
{
    int count;
    foreach (var progress in c)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(progress);
        count = progress;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(count);
}
```

Comment: Can the DLL do a console.writeline?  I need to report the progress as it happens in the DLL without ending the call to the DLL.

Comment: Console.WriteLine was just en example. The important thing is that the method return *several* values.

Comment: But I need to report progress before the return.

Comment: Before the return of what? Did you read my answer? If you return 3 values, the first two will be returned before the third one. Calling a method that has a return is pretty basic stuff.

Comment: Let me describe it this way....lets say I call the DLL and its in the DLL 10 minutes.  After 1 minute I need to report what the DLL has done, ie 10% done.  Then after 2 minutes I need to report what the DLL has done, 20% done.  I need to do this all the way through the processing time its in the DLL.  If I do a return after 1 minute then I don't process the other 90% of what it was going to do.  I need to report this progress on the screen.

Comment: You call won't return in 10 minutes so what are you going to do with the reports and where? Anyway, in my example, you will get the first value after the first iteration in the loop and so on. This is how you report progress.

Comment: I need to report the progress to the screen. And these DLLs will do lots of things and some will take 10 minutes or more.  I need to be able to report progress during the call and not when the call finishes.  I need to report the progress on the screen.

Comment: yield before return makes it stay in the loop?

Comment: Take a look at the Backgroundworker class or the Progress<T> class: http://simplygenius.net/Article/AncillaryAsyncProgress

Comment: yield is - believe it or not - documented in the C# programming guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield

Comment: This works when I use a MessageBox.Show, but when I try to place the messages in a listbox they don't show until the whole thing is finished.  Any way to show the listbox as things are added to it?  Also, why the -1....what the heck?

Comment: By adding a hidden messagebox after each update I'm now able to see the messages in real time.  One issue I still have is the scrollbar isn't enabled until the DLL is done.  Anyway to keep the scrollbar enabled to see the messages in the listbox?

Comment: @ScottS: Please ask a new question if you have another issue. You are not supposed to ask additional questions in the comments field.

Comment: Will do thanks!  I'm still unclear about the -1 though.

Comment: I guess it was -2.  Still not sure where that came from.  Normally that gets explained.